# Can't step into signed assembly with no password set

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, assembly-signing, step-into

In VS2010, when I tell a project to be signed with a key file, but DON'T check the "Protect my key file with a password" box (so a .snk file is generated), I can't step into any code in that assembly when debugging.  If I provide a password (so a .pfx file is generated), however, I can.  I am not delay signing the assembly.  Is there any reason I can't step into the code when I don't protect the key file with a password?

Also, I'm using a project reference within the same solution, not a dll reference (so I'm not just missing my symbols file or anything).  I have cleaned and rebuilt both solutions many times.

Comment: Why would you not add a password to the key file?

Comment: These are all assemblies used internally by a small department with a small development team.  Nothing public facing, nothing released into the wild.

Comment: So why sign the files at all? There's no need to do this for internal applications.

Comment: Because I need the assemblies to be installed in the GAC.  They are HttpModules that are installed in the root web app in IIS, set up in the root web.config.  The only way to do that is to have them in the GAC.